# Error when exporting a project with Log4j2 into a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j2

I'm creating a JAR file for my project that uses Log4j2. I have saved the Log4j2 jars (for CORE and API) in the 'lib' folder under the 'src' folder. Within Eclipse, I exported my project to create the JAR file and I have checked that the 'lib' folder is included/present in the JAR file.

When I run the project from within eclipse, it runs absolutely fine but when I try to execute the jar via the cmd prompt, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\workspace>java -jar ConnectorClient.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
            at com.client.ConnectionClient.<clinit>(ConnectionClient.java:20)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 1 more
```

The line in my code (Line 20) causing the error is:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ConnectionClient.class);
```

It seems as if the Log4j2 jars are not being read. Can somebody be able to help me here please. I've already added the 2 jars in the project's Java Build Path as shown in the image..

[image: Jars added to Java Build Path]

My classpath file (present inside the project folder) includes the 2 jars in questions as shown:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.8.0_05"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: try adding the jar using projectroot right-click configure build path then add external jars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to export a **Runnable Jar file**:

[image: Runnable Jar]

And include the required libraries:

[image]

Comment: this way worked for me but i'm still not sure why it didnt work with my specifying the location of these jars on the ClassPath within Eclipse..I've added my classpath file in my original question. Any advise??

Answer (score 1):

There is a common misconception that a jar can be packaged into another jar. It just won't be available to the classloader, so you will end up with class loading exceptions.

So you either extract the dependency jar into your own jar, as described using eclipse by @PaulVargas, OR you do what 90% of people do and add your dependencies to the classpath of your jar execution:

```
java -classpath libs/*.jar -jar MyJar.jar
```

This means putting all your dependencies in a separate folder (here, libs) NOT packaged within your jar.

Comment: Hi, inorder to check whether its actually the classpath issue thats causing this problem, I added the 2 jars to the classpath of the project by: right-click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add external Jars -> and then select the 2 jar. It didnt work.. I then added these jars in a lib folder and added this 'lib' folder to the 'path' environemnt variable. even that didnt work.. Can you please advise wha tam I doing wrong here??